# Как отключить переброс на файл mail.php при отправки формы?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку отправки формы - форма отправлялась, но не перебрасывало на "/mail.php"? После отправки - должен закрываться этот popup и открываться второй, который благодарит пользователя. Подскажите, как это реализовать? Код HTML:

```html
<div id="modal__wrapper">
  <div class="modal__overlay" id="modal__overlay"></div>
  <div class="modal__window">
    <a href="#" class="modal__close" id="modal__close"></a>
    <div class="modal__content">
      <h3 class="modal__title">
        Заказать обратный звонок
      </h3>
      <form method="post" action="mail.php" class="modal__form" id="modal__form">
        <input type="text" name="firstName" class="modal__item" required placeholder="Имя">
        <input type="email" name="mail" class="modal__item" placeholder="E-mail">
        <input type="tel" name="phoneNumber" class="modal__item" required placeholder="Телефон">
        <button class="modal__btn" id="modal__btn" data-submit>
          Заказать звонок
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно в обработчике клика сабмита формы (на данный момент у вас происходит сабмит по атрибутам самой формы) сделать [preventDefault()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp#:%7E:text=The%20preventDefault()%20method%20cancels,it%20from%20submitting%20a%20form). Вот [статья про событие и метод submit](https://learn.javascript.ru/forms-submit). Саму отправку данных в данном кейсе нужно делать при помощи [ajax запроса](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-intro), на данный момент можно использовать например [fetch](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch). Соотвественно со стороны бэка вам будет необходимо реализовать некоторый api для принятия данного запроса, проще говоря [REST](https://medium.com/@andr.ivas12/rest-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-90a0bca0bc78).

Answer (score 1):

уберите action="mail.php" и отправляйте через функцию к примеру так

```
if ($_POST) {
    include 'mail.php';
    form_mail($_POST);
    echo 'Успешно отправлено'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", "#modal__btn", function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + 'mail.php',
        data: {
            firstName: $('input[name=firstName]').val(),
            mail: $('input[name=mail]').val(),
            first_name: $('input[name=first_name]').val(),
            phoneNumber: $('input[name=phoneNumber]').val()
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {                 
            $('#modal__wrapper').modal('hide');
            // OR $('#modal__wrapper').hide();
            alert('бла-бла');
        }
    });
});
```